# Jenkins Slaves cannot connect to the Master Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, windows

I switched the [Jenkins](https://www.opstrainerz.com/jenkins-training) to using https on port 8080 . After a restart of the Jenkins,the slaves cannot reconnect.

I changed only Jenkins location from Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> Jenkins URL to https://localhost:8080

Know someone who can answer?

Comment: Why do your posts all contain a superfluous link to https://www.opstrainerz.com ? Maybe you should be asking them for help and not S/O if their training is not clear? Are you  misleadingly trying to drive traffic to the site? Do you have an association to the site?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you connect you slaves via ssh or jnlp,
in any case: check if you are able to connect that slave and try telnet it.